# At what altitude starts the drag of the atmosphere lose force on airplanes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, atmospheric-science

If I sail on a boat from North to South the boat will be dragged by the oceans which it floats on, and the oceans are dragged by the Earth.
Now when you go higher let say 10km an airplane will also be dragged by the atmosphere so the rotation of the plane is forced with the rotation or the Earth.

But when you get higher and higher the atmosphere will get less denser and the force of the atmoshpere will drop, till you probably reached satellite level were there is almost no drag of the rotation of the Earth at all.

Now what is the altitude an airplane will begin losing the drag of the atmosphere?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is about a somewhat common misunderstanding of basic mechanics rather than aerodynamic drag. There is no need to "drag" objects in order for them to keep rotating with the earth. Objects will *keep* their angular momentum with respect to the center of the Earth, say, *unless* moments associated with forces acting on them create a change in angular momentum. In other words, the airplane will keep "rotating" with the planet even if there's no atmosphere at all. Your sailboat isn't "dragged" by the ocean, and neither is said ocean "dragged" by the planet.

Answer (score 0):

ESA's dart-like Gravity field and Ocean Circulation Explorer (GOCE) Earth Explorer used to orbit as close to Earth as possible - just 260 km up - to maximize its sensitivity to variations in Earth's gravity field. At that altitude, there is enough atmosphere to exert a small drag. The satellite had an aerodynamic shape and a small engine to keep it in orbit. The mission ended when the engine ran out of fuel.

In 2011, the huge 9.1 Japanese Tohoku earthquake generated atmospheric disturbances. These deflected the satellite. Density variations were also measured. Article and video [here](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/The_Living_Planet_Programme/Earth_Explorers/GOCE/GOCE_the_first_seismometer_in_orbit).

[image]